# How to implement a HTTP API Daemon

Tags: linux, api, http

I'm working for a small Company in the Medical Industry. We have a selfmade Management-Software which, after beeing rewritten, we are going to sell to other, similar Companies. The Software is based on a HTTP API written in PHP. Since we do not want to give away our Code we are currently checking out in which Technology we should rewrite it.

My Question is: How would you implement a HTTP API Daemon which can be installed relatively simple on a Linux machine, without giving away your Code?

Comment: then give them how to access to your http api? example an url, credential and also , parameters you api are expecting if applicable?

Answer (score 1):

**Frameworks and languages**

There are plenty of good languages and frameworks out there for building web applications. If you're looking for a (sort-of-)compiled language you might look into doing something in Java, perhaps with [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) (Disclaimer: the play framework is still relatively new, and despite its popularity may not be ideal for everyone as it's still relatively untested in the wild). I've also heard tell that C# and the Mono projects implementation of [ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) has come a long way, though I haven't used it and can't vouch for it.

I tend to prefer interpreted languages such as Python and Ruby when writing web services. Though these may not fit your use case. The exception being [Go](http://golang.org/) which has become one of my favorites recently. It's quite easy to learn, efficient, and very fast (and compiled).

**Help us help you**

Unfortunately, your question is almost hopelessly vague, so it's hard for me to give a good recommendation. Perhaps you'd consider rephrasing it, laying out some of your requirements, goals, and objectives, so that we can get a bit more of a sense of what will serve you best in the long run?

**Unrelated soapbox warning!**

On a slightly off-topic note, I always encourage the companies I contract for (especially in fields like the medical industry that are often technologically behind) to consider a more open business model. Many small companies try to protect their intellectual property by creating a closed ecosystem which stifles growth and innovation in the long run, and can open them up to major security breaches; Open Source didn't become the new trend in the booming Computer Science industry because it allowed people to steal each others products. It became popular because it was a cheaper, more sustainable alternative to traditional closed source practices. I would argue in favor of protecting your source code via appropriate licensing and legal means instead of sticking with traditional distribution methods. Unlike many people, I think proprietary software still has its place; it's for you to decide if your product fits that model. However, at least consider the pros and cons of the alternative, even if you decide it doesn't fit your business model in the end. *off-soapbox*

Comment: _[Why open-source company culture is important](http://intridea.com/blog/2011/4/22/why-open-source-company-culture-is-important)_ -- Includes an answer to the inevitable question, "But we're a software company, aren't we giving away our most valuable assets? "

Comment: Sounds great; I'll have to give that article a perusal before the next time I try to convince a client to allow me to open source something. Luckily, this is becoming less and less of a problem as people either realize that they can make a lot of money in OSS, or just decide that it's the "cool" thing to do. Thanks again for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your code in php and protect it a few different ways:

- write a small C program with your (possibly obscured or encrypted) source compiled into it that just calls the php executable
- run it through a code obfuscator.  It should run the same but won't be very useful to someone wanting to make modifications
- strip all the commenting out of the code.  Most programs of appreciable size will be confusing enough without any comments that people will be dissuaded from modifying them
- don't worry about it, have your customers legally agree to not give the software to others.  Reputable businesses like your customers generally honor such agreements.
- don't worry about it; give the software away and sell support (contracts or incidents) instead.  AKA the F/OSS business model.

Those last two are a hard sell to management of course; but it depends on your business and technology goals.

If you're set on rewriting the code, the best protection (other than legal restrictions) against others stealing your source is probably a binary-compiled language like C or C++.  Java can be easily decompiled, although there are obfuscators available to make it pretty pointless to do so.  There are also packaging mechanisms for various other languages (such as perl PAR archives, python py2exe, or tcl tclkits) that make it slightly more difficult to view the source, but those are mostly intended to simplify distribution, not to protect the code from malicious eyes.